# Ember ArrayProxy with init not working

Tags: ember.js

I have an class that extends `Ember.ArrayProxy` like:

```
export default Ember.ArrayProxy.extend({
    init() {
      this._super(...arguments);
      this.set('content', Ember.A([]));
      // doing some stuff
    },
});
```

and I am using this like:

```
const myProxy = ProxyClass.create({});
myProxy.addObject(0.5);
```

but because of `init` hook override, the changes aren't propagated, so my template is not changing

```
{{#each myProxy as |someObj|}}
```

I think I am doing something wrong, but funny thing is that I can use `myProxy.content` property to see changes (though I should just refer this by `myProxy`). Maybe someone can point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not provide content property with `ProxyClass.create({ content: [] })`, but instead want to set it in `init()` method.
`ArrayProxy` does have observer which observes changes to `content` property, but the problem here is that observers never fire until after the initialization of the object is complete (thus, content change listeners are not set up properly in this case).

To fix it just set content before calling parent init() method:

```
export default Ember.ArrayProxy.extend({
  init() {
     this.set('content', []);
     this._super(...arguments);
    // doing some stuff
  }
});
```